# android:background with Drawable in AndroidX

Tags: android, androidx, classcastexception

I have searched SO for an answer for my question and didn't found, please let me know if it has been answered elsewhere.

I had some buttons in my app:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scaninbutton"
    android:layout_above="@+id/scanoutbutton"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonshape2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"/>
```

Beeing buttonshape2 as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<corners
    android:radius="30dp"
    />
<solid
    android:color="@color/frontcolor"
    />
<padding
    android:left="0dp"
    android:top="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:bottom="0dp"
    />
<size
    android:width="100dp"
    android:height="40dp"
    />
</shape>
```

It was working fine, but since I migrated my app to Androidx it is not working anymore. How can I set my drawable as a background for components?

Thank you.

EDIT:

Also, in some buttons in my app I have this code:

```
GradientDrawable bgShape = (GradientDrawable)askQuestion.getBackground();
                bgShape.setColor(Color.parseColor(almacen.getColor()));
```

it fails with

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable
```

...but it only fails in SOME buttons. In the login page I have this code:

```
GradientDrawable bgShape3 = (GradientDrawable)entrar.getBackground();
    bgShape3.setColor(getColor(R.color.frontcolor));
```

And it is working! Being the only difference that askQuestion button is local variable, and entrar button is global variable. It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Are you getting some error or the drawable is just not showing? Maybe the `backgroundTint` is somehow set to alpha = 0, did you try setting it to some other value?

Comment: The button is showing, but the style is not applying. It has no rounded borders, the color is not applying, etc. It has no alpha value.